# (type is invalid -- expected a string ...) (Unsupported Server Component type: undefined at stringify) errors | while following Navbar example code

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, next.js13

I am having [these errors](https://pastebin.com/crUmz2Q8) after I copy-pasted the first example's code from React-Bootstrap's [Navbar documentation](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/components/navbar/) into a freshly created Next.js app using `npx create-next-app`, with all default options and App Router enabled.

My base `page.js` file looks like this:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from './page.module.css'
import Header from '../components/Header'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <Header/>
      fiasnofndisnf
    </main>
  )
}
```

My `Header.js` file looks like this:

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';

function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Navbar expand="lg" className="bg-body-tertiary">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
            <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
                Another action
              </NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Divider />
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">
                Separated link
              </NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
}

export default BasicExample;
```

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "test2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "next": "13.5.6",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.9.1",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.5.6"
  }
}
```

I was having this issue in a different main project, so this example generates the problem from as basic of a test-project as possible.

All `npm outdated` packages were `npm update`d, Next.js is on the latest version.

For this error, online and on StackOverflow I only found examples of this error happening when somebody misspelled component names, or forgot the `default` when exporting the function. But in this most basic environment, this code is directly taken from React-Bootstrap's documentation.

The only way I have found to get rid of the errors is when I remove all `.` operators:

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';

function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Navbar expand="lg" className="bg-body-tertiary">
      <Container>
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                Another action
                Separated link
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
}

export default BasicExample;
```

Only this compiles with no errors. This suggests that using the components without the `.` operators (the CamelCase) ones works, and it does for some of them. But this seems awfully inconvenient and not the right solution.

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a proper solution?